# Are macOS libraries for Apple Silicon any different?

Tags: c++, linux, macos, lib, apple-silicon

A library can be static or dynamic. Respectively, on macOS it can be a `.a` or a `.dylib` file, as far as I know.

Let's say I'm going to use it for both, the old (non silicon) apple computers (i.e. those running Catalina) and the new computers with M cpu (i.e. those running Monterey).

Does the binary, the `.a` or `.dylib`, is different for each case?

Should the vendor provide a specific binary for apple-silicon?

How the `.so` libraries go in this context?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, they are different, people usually use [lipo](https://ss64.com/osx/lipo.html) to merge multiple architectures together (when it is not part of the build process).